# Twitter "Like" and "Retweet" buttons don't work on Tor Browser anymore

Tags: firefox, error

This is probably a simple issue but I cannot seem to figure it out. I can no longer like or retweet tweets using the Tor Browser. This started several days ago. The Android app works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: try to install Firebug or use a develoer tools built-in to take a closer look at the "like" button/link and what is happening when you press it. Try to see the differences for a like-button code in clearnet and Tor connection cases - maybe the server is disabling it and not emmitting the code into the page, so it's in "unclickable" state?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue here. BarneyTodds conclusion seems to be right. In addition to that I'm having trouble to view the sent and recieved Direct Messages (might be related, as it started at about the same time), but could not discern what's the problem using developer tools. I've downloaded and extracted a fresh copy of the latest tor browser bundle (6.5), to rule out a persistent misconfiguration. I'd think that, as probably tons of people are using Twitter via TOR, there should be many effected users, yet I've not found any other bug reports about this. Strange.

Comment: Same problem. Started around the 7th or 8th of Feb. It could be because Twitter taking measures to improve quality. Troll armies, fake followers etc. are using Tor a lot. But I think that something just when wrong when Twitter was adjusting. Only thing you can do is wait. They will fix it sooner or lateer - if it is not strategy.

Comment: I don't doubt twitter is doing this on purpose in an effort to crackdown on trolls. This is the Internet, and things like that are going to happen no matter what you do. It's best to come psychologically prepared than limit all users' abilities.

Comment: Now I can't "retweet" posts either.

Comment: It is also discussed in Tor's bug tracker: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21555

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed for the next Tor Browser release. Please see the ticket below and test if possible:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21555

Answer (score 1):

I just verified this issue. It appears that the auth_token is not being sent in the JSON request form, even though it is included in the headers.

```
Request URL:  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json

Request method:  POST

Remote address: 0.0.0.0:443

Status code:  400 Bad Request

Version:  HTTP/1.1


Response: 
JSON

errors: Object

0: Object

code: 215

message: “Bad Authentication data.”


Params:

Form Data

id: “xxxxxxxxxxx”

tweet_stat_count: “xx”

Request Body:

id=xxxxxx&tweet_stat_count=xx
```