# Twitter and Tor

Tags: javascript

Recently, when I use Twitter via Tor, I get an error message "Sorry, something went wrong" when I click on the heart icon (to favorite a tweet). All the other functions work. When I use regular Firefox, I do not have this problem. I have also tried a variety of Tor circuits, but that did not work. Is this some kind of JavaScript setting issue?

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/new-twitter-issue

Comment: I read 13995 new twitter issue. It is a bit over my head. Am I correct in understanding that this is a bug in either Tor or Twitter, or is there something I am supposed to adjust in Tor parameters?

Comment: I have no means to test since twitter no longer likes anonymous users.

Comment: I have had the same issue. I suspect Twitter doesn't like Tor browser. It first started with limiting my likes on one account, and then rewteets. My other account had NO issues at all. Now I can't like or retweet from there either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter "Like" and "Retweet" buttons don't work on Tor Browser anymore](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/twitter-like-and-retweet-buttons-dont-work-on-tor-browser-anymore)

Comment: In this very minute that I write I have the same problem, notifications arrive, but when I go to read the news page it does not work, there is something wrong, Twitter is spiteful, try to solve if not it makes no sense to use Twitter with Orbot.